# Accessing Windows from Linux/Mac by name using TCP/IP

Tags: macos, networking, router, dns, home-networking

What are some solutions to access Windows by its computer name from Linux and Mac using TCP/IP. That is, from terminal I want to be able to ping my Windows PCs using its host name.

My setup is:

- Various machines running Ubuntu, Windows XP and OS X.
- Networked using a consumer grade wireless router which provides DHCP.
- The only DNS is the ISP's, which resolves Internet names and not local host names.

The Windows machines can ping each other by name. The Ubuntu and OS X machines can only ping  Windows by IP address (name doesn't work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up going with multicast DNS by installing Apple's Bonjour. Now I can address the Windows PCs by using the address `hostname.local` from the OS X and Linux machines.

Answer (score 1):

you can edit your /etc/hosts file to add the ip addresses to internal DNS support.

Obviously a sync solution (meaning using a DNS server in your router or setting up a DNS server on one of your boxes that the router points to)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your router supports DNS forwarding. Often DNS forwarders will serve windows hostnames if they come through as a DNS request.

You might also make sure that Samba is fully installed on the linux machines and enabled on the Mac.

Comment: DNS Forwarding is a feature that allows DNS requests to be forwarded to a specific set of downstream servers rather than using root hints for unresolvable names. It doesn't have anything to do with local hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `wins` to the end of the `hosts` line in the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` will make Linux use the Windows network browsing thingy for name resolution.

(You will need to have the `winbind` package installed for it to work. It will probably already be installed.)