# Is there a way to connect to a Windows machine from Linux by name instead of by IP?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, home-networking, hostname

In my home network, the Linux machines all have avahi installed and can access each other by their hostnames instead of by their IP

```
ping laptop.local
```

But for the Windows machine I could only manage to connect to it by directly passing its IP address:

```
ping 192.168.254.146
```

I tried multiple variations of its hostname and none of them worked.

```
#All of these give an "unknown host" error
ping IE11WIN7
ping IE11WIN7.local
ping IE11Win7
ping IE11Win7.local
```

Is there a way to, from the Linux command line, connect to the windows machine by passing the hostname instead of the IP?

By the way, I noticed that the machine in question does appear on the "windows network" list if I try to access it via my file browser (Thunar) so if possible I would like if the command-line accessing used a similar trick instead of me having to end up resorting to editing my etc/hosts file by hand.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/149015) suggests that the "hostname.local" scheme should also work for windows machines but its not working for me...

Comment: Smbclient accepts names, nmblookup can convert name to IP.

Comment: As workaround, if you are interested in the file sharing in your local network, it's always possible to mount the _windows shared directory_ under the linux _filesystem_ (e.g. in your example `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.254.146/C -o credentials=/root/.smbcredential  /mnt/WhereYouWant `; here you have to put the credential in the file `/root/.smbcred` readable only by root for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

You need SMB (SAMBA) services running and correctly configured to do that, in your linux (maybe, it's possible with a particular configuration of avahi for smb protocol).